# Navbar Sticky Shrink Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple nav bar to work sticky shrink of nav bar.

HTML:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header></header>

    <nav id="nav" class="nav">
        <div class="nav__inner">
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt id error ut delectus a sapiente accusantium quam, laudantium, atque laborum, distinctio. Commodi perspiciatis ipsa ducimus labore, iure dignissimos fugit quae.</p>
    </div>

    <footer>This is footer</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:-

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: 'helvetica neue';
    letter-spacing: 0.03em;
    color: #333;
}

header {
    height: 150px;
    background: black;
}

footer {
    height: 50px;
    background: black;
    color: dodgerblue;
}

.nav {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    height: 80px;
    background: dodgerblue;
    transition: height 200ms ease;

    &.is-shrunk {
        height: 50px;
    }
}
```

JS:-

```
const nav = document.getElementById('nav');

const navFromTop = nav.offsetTop;

const navHeight = nav.offsetHeight;

const distanceScrolled = () => {
   return window.pageYOffset;
};

const isScrolledEnough = () => {
   return (distanceScrolled() > navFromTop + navHeight);
};

const setIsShrunk = (value) => {
    if (value && isScrolledEnough()) {
        nav.classList.add('is-shrunk');
    } else if (!value) {
        nav.classList.remove('is-shrunk');
    }
};

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    setIsShrunk(distanceScrolled() > navHeight);
});
```

I want this code to shrink the blue nav bar from 80px height to 50px height on page scrolling.

What i did was copy code from [Sticky shrink](https://codepen.io/davidpmccormick/pen/BWmabx?q=sticky%20shrinking&order=popularity&depth=everything&show_forks=false). But i am not getting the effect as shown in the link mentioned. The blue nav bar didn't shrink on scrolling the page as is done in the link. What could be the possible problem and the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Just change :**

```
&.is-shrunk {
        height: 50px;
}
```

**to the following and take it out of the nested .nav selector in CSS.**

```
.nav.is-shrunk {
        height: 50px;
}
```

> Ampersand (&) is a SASS nesting selector and you could do the same
>   operation without nesting as shown below.

```js
const nav = document.getElementById('nav');

const navFromTop = nav.offsetTop;

const navHeight = nav.offsetHeight;

const distanceScrolled = () => {
  return window.pageYOffset;
};

const isScrolledEnough = () => {
  return (distanceScrolled() > navFromTop + navHeight);
};

const setIsShrunk = (value) => {
  if (value && isScrolledEnough()) {
    nav.classList.add('is-shrunk');
  } else if (!value) {
    nav.classList.remove('is-shrunk');
  }
};

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  setIsShrunk(distanceScrolled() > navHeight);
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'helvetica neue';
  letter-spacing: 0.03em;
  color: #333;
}

header {
  height: 150px;
  background: black;
}

footer {
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
  color: dodgerblue;
}

.nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 80px;
  background: dodgerblue;
  transition: height 200ms ease;
}

.nav.is-shrunk {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<header></header>

<nav id="nav" class="nav">
  <div class="nav__inner">
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt id error ut delectus a sapiente accusantium quam, laudantium, atque laborum, distinctio. Commodi perspiciatis ipsa ducimus labore, iure dignissimos fugit quae.</p>
  <p>Nesciunt eos recusandae adipisci nostrum illum eius. Tempora nemo necessitatibus temporibus quaerat laudantium dolorem minima blanditiis sapiente earum fugiat commodi officiis, magni ducimus corporis, ad! Maiores perspiciatis aperiam quod nemo.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt id error ut delectus a sapiente accusantium quam, laudantium, atque laborum, distinctio. Commodi perspiciatis ipsa ducimus labore, iure dignissimos fugit quae.</p>
  <p>Nesciunt eos recusandae adipisci nostrum illum eius. Tempora nemo necessitatibus temporibus quaerat laudantium dolorem minima blanditiis sapiente earum fugiat commodi officiis, magni ducimus corporis, ad! Maiores perspiciatis aperiam quod nemo.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt id error ut delectus a sapiente accusantium quam, laudantium, atque laborum, distinctio. Commodi perspiciatis ipsa ducimus labore, iure dignissimos fugit quae.</p>
  <p>Nesciunt eos recusandae adipisci nostrum illum eius. Tempora nemo necessitatibus temporibus quaerat laudantium dolorem minima blanditiis sapiente earum fugiat commodi officiis, magni ducimus corporis, ad! Maiores perspiciatis aperiam quod nemo.</p>
  <p>Quisquam magni doloribus deserunt rerum, expedita iste numquam ipsum velit beatae, dolores optio sapiente corporis voluptatum mollitia nemo excepturi eveniet provident dolorem facilis incidunt minus aliquam error quas. Distinctio, exercitationem!</p>
  <p>Esse sapiente dolore labore, fuga nobis voluptates explicabo odio asperiores, quod repudiandae totam harum tempora praesentium natus. Blanditiis, sint id sit, ab impedit fuga aliquam distinctio harum, ex molestias voluptates!</p>
  <p>Cumque laborum, ad sequi, reiciendis illum non vero voluptatum libero consequatur quod vitae voluptatem quibusdam incidunt inventore temporibus omnis optio sint quasi soluta. Reprehenderit omnis inventore, doloremque repudiandae minus recusandae.</p>
  <p>Reiciendis hic, placeat laborum iure quo ratione ex perspiciatis, error perferendis sed facilis animi corrupti delectus soluta libero id eligendi iusto magnam itaque. Facere, ducimus. Eveniet officiis quod, vero asperiores.</p>
</div>

<footer>This is footer</footer>
```

Comment: i have already tried that....but still not working for me...what could be the problem....

Comment: @Space Run the snippet and in your code give enough data so it is able to scroll which you havn't.

Comment: ya, i ran it...the snippet works fine but when i use it in my pc it didn't work...

Comment: Check your CSS against the code, that's the only thing that needed modification to work. And yeah, enough content to make the content scroll down enough to shrink it. Use Inspector in your browser to see if there are any errors in your code.

Comment: Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of null....error after page inspection...

Comment: @Space Add your javascript code at the end of your body not in the beginning or head tags. or enclose the entire script in window.addEventListener('load', function() { //Code here });